# Memory allocation issues with the LPC1788 microcontroller

Tags: c, microcontroller, lpc, threadx

I'm fairly new to programming microcontrollers; I've been working with the LPC1788 for a couple of weeks now.

One problem I've been having recently is that I'm running out of memory much sooner than I expect to. I've tested how much memory seems to be available by testing how large a block of contiguous memory I can malloc, and the result is 972 bytes. Allocation is done starting at address 0x10000000 (the start of the on-chip SRAM that should be around 64kB on this board).

The program I'm working on at the moment is meant to act as a simple debugger that utilises the LCD and allows messages to be printed to it. I have one string that will constantly be "added to" by new messages, and then the whole message will be printed on the LCD. When the message's length down the screen goes past the vertical boundary, it will delete the oldest messages (the ones nearer the top) until it fits. However, I can only add about 7 additional messages before it refuses to allocate more memory. If needed, the main.c for the project is hosted at http://pastebin.com/bwUdpnD3

Earlier I also started work on a project that uses the threadX RTOS to create and execute several threads. When I tried including use of the LCD in that program, I found memory to be very limited there aswell. The LCD seems to store all pixel data starting from the SDRAM base address, but I'm not sure if that's the same thing as the SRAM I'm using.

What I need is a way to allocate memory enough to allow several threads to function or large strings to be stored, while being able to utilise the LCD. One possibility might be to use buffers or other areas of memory, but I'm not quite sure how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

tl;dr: Quickly running out of allocatable memory on SRAM when trying to print out large strings on the LCD.

EDIT 1: A memory leak was noticed with the variable currMessage. I think that's been fixed now:

```
strcpy(&trimMessage[1], &currMessage[trimIndex+1]);

// Frees up the memory allocated to currMessage from last iteration
// before assigning new memory.
free(currMessage);
currMessage = malloc((msgSize - trimIndex) * sizeof(char));
for(int i=0; i < msgSize - trimIndex; i++)
{
  currMessage[i] = trimMessage[i];
}
```

EDIT 2: Implemented memory leak fixes. Program works a lot better now, and I feel pretty stupid.

Comment: It's probably heap fragmentation or maybe even just a memory leak - you'll need to give a lot more thought to your memory management strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful when choosing to use dynamic memory allocation in an embedded environment, especially with constrained memory.  You can very easily end up fragmenting the memory space such that the biggest hole left is 972 bytes.

If you must allocate from the heap, do it once, and then hang onto the memory--almost like a static buffer.  If possible, use a static buffer and avoid the allocation all together.  If you must have dynamic allocation, keeping it to fixed sized blocks will help with the fragmentation.

Unfortunately, it does take a bit of engineering effort to overcome the fragmentation issue.  It is worth the effort, and it does make the system much more robust though.

As for SRAM vs SDRAM, they aren't the same.  I'm not familiar with threadX, and whether or not they have a Board Support Package (BSP) for your board, but in general, SDRAM has to be setup.  That means the boot code has to initialize the memory controller, setup the timings, and then enable that space.  Depending on your heap implementation, you need to dynamically add it or--more likely--you need to compile with your heap space pointing to where it will ultimately live (in SDRAM space).  Then, you have to make sure to come up and get the memory controlled configured and activated before actually using the heap.

One other thing to watch out for, you may actually be running code from the SRAM space, and some of that space is also reserved for processor exception tables.  That whole space may not be available, and may live through two different addresses (0x00000000 and 0x10000000) for instance.  I know in some other ARM9 processors, this is common.  You can boot from flash, which gets mapped initially into the 0x00000000 space, and then you do a song and dance to copy the booter into SRAM and map SRAM into that space.  At that point, you can boot into something like Linux, who expects to be able to update the tables that live down at 0.

BTW, it does look like you have some memory leaks in the code you posted.  Namely, currentMessage is never freed... only overwritten with a new pointer.  Those blocks are then lost forever.

Comment: First off, thanks for pointing out the memory leak. I've modified the code for printMessage() (details of change will be editted into original post) and hopefully that's sorted now, although my program still seems to run out of memory at the same time.

The suggestion to dynamically allocate once and hang on to the memory seems like the best thing I can do right now. Maybe make a 500-char array for currMessage at the start and just modify the characters inside it. Still leaves only about 400 bytes perhaps for anything else I want to deal with though, hm.

Comment: Another memory leak exists around line 177... similar issue.

Comment: Good point. I corrected the code in trimMessage() when I thought I was in printMessage() (the two functions look sort of similar). Both contain memory leaks, but seeing as I'm not calling trimMessage() from anywhere for now, it explains why the correction there had no effect. I'm having some issues with fixing the one in printMessage(), but I'll update when it's working. Ty.